# Is it possible to downscale depth texture on Metal?

Tags: ios, 3d, metal, depth-buffer

I want to downscale depth texture to half of it width and height and then attach to smaller render buffer for continue rendering.

`MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float` is read only format for compute shaders.

I wonder if any of those are possible:

1. Blit from R32 to Depth32
2. `MPSImageLanczosScale` with Depth32

Or maybe there is another solution?

Comment: I think `MPSImageLanczosScale` will use compute shader underneath, so Depth32 won't work.

Comment: Maybe doing a separate geometry only pass to a downsized buffer will work, if it's not too much overhead.

Comment: But it seems that blitting to R32F, then scaling and then blitting back is the best option.

Comment: @Spo1ler blit not allowed from R32F to Depth32Float, just tested after asking question.  :(

Comment: Also `newTextureViewWithPixelFormat:` not valid. Error at runtime

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You can write a compute shader that will just read depth texture, scale it and write the result into downsized R32F.

Comment: @Spo1ler I have it :)

Comment: Well then, the options are exhausted. Except, maybe copying from texture to buffer and then back to texture of other format.